# How too make if else check using boolen in XSLT (transunion)

Tags: xslt, if-statement

I have xml like this

```
<fileSummary>
      <fileHitIndicator>regularHit</fileHitIndicator>
      <ssnMatchIndicator>noMatch</ssnMatchIndicator>
      <consumerStatementIndicator>true</consumerStatementIndicator>
      <market>32</market>
      <submarket>QU</submarket>
      <creditDataStatus>
        <suppressed>false</suppressed>
        <doNotPromote>
          <indicator>false</indicator>
        </doNotPromote>
        <freeze>
          <indicator>false</indicator>
        </freeze>
        <minor>false</minor>
        <disputed>false</disputed>
      </creditDataStatus>
      <inFileSinceDate estimatedCentury="false" estimatedDay="false" estimatedMonth="false" estimatedYear="false">2004-02-02</inFileSinceDate>
    </fileSummary>
```

I want to make check if indicator value is true then show some text otherwise hide it.

```
<freeze>
    <indicator>false</indicator>
</freeze>
```

I am new to XSLT, please let me know.

Comment: Use the `xsl:choose` statement. See here : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp

Comment: I'd start off by learning the correct name of the tool you are proposing to use.

Comment: i made following check but i am unable to do it     <xsl:when test="subject/subjectRecord/fileSummary/creditDatastatus/freeze/indicator='true'">    still having issue it work for true or false...

Answer (score 0):

If the description of what you want to achieve includes an "otherwise", then you're not in need of an `xsl:if`, but an `xsl:choose`.

In the example below it is crucial that the template matches the `freeze` element, i.e. that the context of the `xsl:choose` is the `freeze` element.

**EDIT**: Added a complete example based on your updated input.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="freeze">
   <result>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="indicator = 'false'">
         <xsl:text>Indicator is false!</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:text>Indicator is not false!</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>Indicator is false!</result>
```

Comment: i put check like that    <xsl:when test="subject/subjectRecord/fileSummary/creditDatastatus/freeze/indicator='true'">     but when the value is true it does not show the text

Comment: Please edit your question and include a _complete_ XML input document and a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet. Then, I'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="indicator">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".='true'">
                <xsl:text>some text</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to a your input (slightly modified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fileSummary>
    <fileHitIndicator>regularHit</fileHitIndicator>
    <ssnMatchIndicator>noMatch</ssnMatchIndicator>
    <consumerStatementIndicator>true</consumerStatementIndicator>
    <market>32</market>
    <submarket>QU</submarket>
    <creditDataStatus>
        <suppressed>false</suppressed>
        <doNotPromote>
            <indicator>true</indicator>
        </doNotPromote>
        <freeze>
            <indicator>false</indicator>
        </freeze>
        <minor>false</minor>
        <disputed>false</disputed>
    </creditDataStatus>
    <inFileSinceDate estimatedCentury="false" estimatedDay="false" estimatedMonth="false" estimatedYear="false">2004-02-02</inFileSinceDate>
</fileSummary>
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><fileSummary>
    <fileHitIndicator>regularHit</fileHitIndicator>
    <ssnMatchIndicator>noMatch</ssnMatchIndicator>
    <consumerStatementIndicator>true</consumerStatementIndicator>
    <market>32</market>
    <submarket>QU</submarket>
    <creditDataStatus>
        <suppressed>false</suppressed>
        <doNotPromote>
            some text
        </doNotPromote>
        <freeze>

        </freeze>
        <minor>false</minor>
        <disputed>false</disputed>
    </creditDataStatus>
    <inFileSinceDate estimatedCentury="false" estimatedDay="false" estimatedMonth="false" estimatedYear="false">2004-02-02</inFileSinceDate>
</fileSummary>
```